# Как отправить ссылку в Instagram Direct?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При отправке ссылки в директ инстаграм, в Form Data отправляются значения client_context и mutation_token. Откуда берутся эти значения, либо как их можно расшифровать? Может быть у кого есть готовое решение? Instabot к сожалению устарел, и в нем эти параметры не передаются